# Can we mix KnockoutJs and EmberJs in our application?

Tags: ember.js, knockout.js, handlebars.js

I have couple of pages written in KnockoutJs and I want to add these 4 pages to the application which is written in Emberjs+HandlebarsJs. Can we do this? KnockoutJs is based on MVVM pattern, EmberJs is based on MVC. So is my idea right? Can we do this at all? It will be great if I can get answer with explanation.

Comment: It's kinda hard to integrate Ember with other frameworks or libraries, it wants to manage everything about your app. You can have two apps side by side tho.

Comment: @FezVrasta : Thanks for the response but can you please elaborate on it or share me any links which talks about these things?

Comment: It won't be easy, but you could have your Ember app rendering in an element other than `body`, but rather a child element. (see [Ember.Application.rootElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#property_rootElement))